# can we get filename from byteArrayResource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It's about uploading `xlsx` file. Initially im getting `xlsx` file as `javax.servlet.http.Part` and trying to convert as `ByteArrayResource` Since i need to pass via `RestTemplate`.

`new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(input.getFile().getInputStream())`

Here `input.getFile()` is `javax.servlet.http.Part`

As im converting here into `ByteArrayResource` and sending back to another Layer for business logic, can i get `filename` from `ByteArrayResource` ?

Anyhow we can get `filename` from `Part`, I want to know is that possible to get `filename` from `ByteArrayResource` or `ByteArray` ?

Comment: It's not possible. Filename is a file system property, it is not part of the data blocks. If you just have the byte array, you can't get the original file name.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to use `FileNameAwareByteArrayResource` as outlined in [Spring-boot MultipartFile issue with ByteArrayResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416015/spring-boot-multipartfile-issue-with-bytearrayresource).

You'll be able to get the filename from it then.

Comment: Thank you Rob for another work around. Anyhow i can not accept this as answer as the question is different. Thanks!

Comment: FileNameAwareByteArrayResource is a type of ByteArrayResource so it is the only possible answer really Just swap FileNameAwareByteArrayResource for ByteArrayResource and you can get the fileName. It's the only way to get filename from it. You can't get it from ByteArrayResource or ByteArray. ByteArrayResource has no fileName.

Answer (score 3):

This is late but if anyone is still looking for an answer.

`ByteArrayResource` doesn't have any filename by default. See the super class method `AbstractResource.getFileName()`, it returns null. So until you set the name explicitly while creating `ByteArrayResource`, it will remain null.

You can achieve this like

```
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(bytearray) {
        @Override
        public String getFilename() {
            return "somename";
        };
    }
```

Now how to use the actual file name instead of "somename". If you're using Spring, you can define a method in your controller accepting Multipart as an argument.

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> handleFileOperation(Multipart file) {}
```

Once you get the MultipartFile instance, you can use it the way you want.